# Intensity uncertainty, $\Delta \bar{I}(t) \approx \frac{1}{2}N \varepsilon_{0} c E_{0}^{2}$, of collisionally broadened source

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, atomic-physics, quantum-optics

According to my professor's notes, the intensity uncertainty of a collisionally broadened photon source is:
$$\Delta \bar{I}(t) \approx \frac{1}{2}N \varepsilon_{0} c E_{0}^{2}$$
with N being the number of atoms and $E_0$ the field amplitude emitted from each atom. The notes do not explain the expression in more detail and there is no derivation. Can someone point me in the direction of an explanation or derivation of this expression?